# Convert a row into two row in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Attendance table with columns (Check_In, Check_Out). I want to split each row and insert into another column. How can I accomplish that?

For example:

```
Check_In, Check_Out 
23:10   , 08:10
```

Want to convert it to one column table

```
Entry_Time
23:10
08:10
```

Comment: Please read the instructions on the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) on how to write a good SQL question and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: `SELECT Check_In FROM table UNION ALL SELECT Check_Out FROM table`. But how will you distinguish them later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply` :

```
select tt.*
from table t cross apply
     ( values (Check_In), (Check_Out) 
     ) tt(Entry_Time)
order by Entry_Time;
```

Comment: @abdy . . . This is the better approach, because it scans the table (or calculates the subquery) only once.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `union all`:

```
select check_in entry_time from mytable
union all select check_out from mytable
```

For this to be easier to consume, you would need to add at least one column to the resultset so you can identify from which record the data originally came from. Assuming that the primary key of the table is `id`:

```
select id, check_in entry_time from mytable
union all select id, check_out from mytable
```

Comment: Don't forget to alias the new output column